# CPU--Limit Exception

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, cpulimit, cpu-time

I have written a batch which is giving APEX CPU LIMIT Exception,
can anyone help.

```
global class BatchTest implements Database.Batchable<sobject> {


list<Account> AccountstoUpdate= new list<Account>();
private Map<String, Decimal> mapIsoToConversion = new Map<String, Decimal>();
public String sOrgCurrencyIso {get;set;}
public boolean RecordsInScope=FALSE;

    
public Integer iadded = 0; 
global final String sQuery;
public List<String> lstExceptions = new List<String>();


global BatchTest(){
    if(Test.isRunningTest())
        sQuery = 'Select h.LastModifiedDate, h.Id From Hierarchy__c h where h.LastModifiedDate=TODAY';
    else
        sQuery = 'Select h.LastModifiedDate, h.Id From Hierarchy__c h where h.LastModifiedDate=YESTERDAY';
        //sQuery = 'Select h.LastModifiedDate, h.Id From Hierarchy__c h where h.LastModifiedDate=TODAY';
}
public void prepareConversionRates(){
    //fetch from CurrencyType  instead
    for(CurrencyType dcr : [select  IsoCode, 
                                    ConversionRate,
                                    IsCorporate 
                                from CurrencyType
                                where IsActive = true 
                                ]){
        if(dcr.IsCorporate){
            this.sOrgCurrencyIso = dcr.IsoCode;
        }
        this.mapIsoToConversion.put(dcr.IsoCode, dcr.ConversionRate);           
    }
}




global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(this.sQuery);
}

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Hierarchy__c> scope){
    this.RecordsInScope=TRUE;
    this.prepareConversionRates();
    //system.debug('this.sOrgCurrencyIso ' + this.sOrgCurrencyIso);
    if(this.sOrgCurrencyIso == null){
        return;
    }   
    
    set<id> hid = new set<id>();

    for(Hierarchy__c a :scope){

        hid.add(a.id);

    }
 
    map<id,list<Account>> accmap=new map<id,list<Account>>();
    set<id> acceff = new set<id>();

    for(account a :[select id,a.Hierarchy__c,Hierarchy_Id__c,Man_Committed_Expected_Funding_Amount__c,CurrencyIsoCode from account a where a.Hierarchy__c in :hid]){
 
        if (Accmap.containsKey(a.Hierarchy__c)) {
                    Accmap.get(a.Hierarchy__c).add(a);
        } 
        else {
                    Accmap.put(a.Hierarchy__c, new List<Account>{ a});
        }


        acceff.add(a.id);
    }
    
    for (account a :[Select id,Hierarchy__c,Acc_Committed_Expected_Funding_Amount__c,CurrencyIsoCode from account where id in : acceff]){
        // TO DO -  convert amount to account currency query currencytype object
        decimal TempAmount =0.00;
        
        for(account ac: Accmap.get(a.Hierarchy__c)){
            //system.debug('MANAMOUNT'+ ac.id +' ' + ac.Man_Committed_Expected_Funding_Amount__c );
            //system.debug('Code'+ ac.id +' ' + ac.CurrencyIsoCode );
            if(ac.Hierarchy_Id__c.contains(a.id) && ac.id <> a.id && ac.Man_Committed_Expected_Funding_Amount__c <> null) {
             TempAmount+= (ac.Man_Committed_Expected_Funding_Amount__c / mapIsoToConversion.get(ac.CurrencyIsoCode));   
            }
            //system.debug('TEMP'+ ac.id +' ' + TempAmount); 
        }
        //system.debug('Malc'+ a.id +' ' + TempAmount );
        a.Acc_Committed_Expected_Funding_Amount__c=TempAmount * mapIsoToConversion.get(a.CurrencyIsoCode);
        AccountsToUpdate.add(a);
    }
    
    if(AccountsToUpdate !=null &&  !AccountsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
        AccountTriggerHandler.skipTriggerLogic = true;
        List<Database.SaveResult> lstResults = Database.update(AccountsToUpdate, false);
        for(Integer i=0; i < lstResults.size(); i++){
            if(!lstResults[i].isSuccess()){
                String sError = '';
                for(Database.Error err : lstResults[i].getErrors()){
                    sError += err.getMessage();
                }
                this.lstExceptions.add(AccountsToUpdate[i].Id +':' +AccountsToUpdate[i].Name +' : failed Update: '+ sError);
            }else{
                this.iadded++;
            }               
        }
        AccountTriggerHandler.skipTriggerLogic = false;
    }
  
 
 
 }
 
  
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    
    /*string sHTML='';
    
    if(this.sOrgCurrencyIso == null  && this.RecordsInScope==TRUE){
        sHTML += 'Failed because of org currency evaluation problem.';
    }
    else{
    
        sHTML += 'Records Updated successfully: '+ this.iadded +' <br />Process exceptions : <br /><br />';
    
        if(!this.lstExceptions.isEmpty()){
            for(String s :this.lstExceptions){
                sHTML += s +'<br /><br />';
            }
        }
        else{
        sHTML += 'No issues detected during batch run.';
        }
    }
    String sCurrentUserEmail = '';
    List<User> lstUser = [select Email from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1];
    if(lstUser != null && !lstUser.isEmpty() && lstUser[0].Email != null){
        sCurrentUserEmail = lstUser[0].Email;
    }
    List<String> lstEmails = new List<String>{'ASISalesforcePlatformTeam@email.aberdeenstandard.com'};
    if(sCurrentUserEmail != null && sCurrentUserEmail != ''){
        lstEmails.add(sCurrentUserEmail);
    }
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setToAddresses(lstEmails); 
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Committed Expected Funding Hierarchy Batch');
    mail.setSubject('Committed Expected Funding Hierarchy Batch - process completed.'+Datetime.now().format());
    mail.setHTMLBody(sHTML);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});*/

}
```

}

NOTE : for(account ac: Accmap.get(a.Hierarchy__c)) --  This particular line is throwing APEX CPU limit exception

Answer (score 0):

The line the limit exception is reported is just where the limit is exceeded: the cause is the overall flow of the code.

It looks like you have an outer loop and an inner loop. With such a structure, the limit consumption grows exponentially rather than linearly so avoiding that (where possible) makes sense. So changing the inner loop to a map computed before you enter the outer loop is an area to look at.

You mention using batching: ensuring that the number of records processed in the `execute` of a batch is determinate is important, as then the number of records per batch can be sized as necessary.

I suggest you add to your question what you are aiming to do with the overall batch code, as the code you have posted is incomplee.

Comment: Updated  As per above comment